# How to return a function calling another function based on the input?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm really quite new to Haskell and I need to return a function that "has modified" the inputted function.

I guess you cant copy and modify the original function (based on some condition) so you have to implement own behaviour directly and then call the original function?

This is my approach:

```
switchFirstEgg eggCarton = if eggCarton 1 == 0
                                then switchedCarton where switchedCarton position = if position == 1 then 2 else eggCarton position
                                else if eggCarton 1 == 1
                                        then switchedCarton where switchedCarton position = if position == 1 then 0 else eggCarton position
                                        else if eggCarton 1 == 2
                                                then switchedCarton where switchedCarton position = if position == 1 then 1 else eggCarton position
                                                else switchedCarton where switchedCarton position = eggCarton position
```

The error I get from the GHCI is

> haskell/eggcartons.hs:42:54: parse error on input ‘where’

which points to the first word after the first `where`.

(For reference: I also tried to set more brackets here http://pastebin.com/2wTqAqpm and I tried doing it with guards http://pastebin.com/RVm28Y7n, but that's only making it worse without thouroughly understanding that? At least guards worked for me here http://pastebin.com/uQeFwLU5)

I searched for returning functions in Haskell but I only got a few random info that I used with the `where` things I have done.

Is my concept right? Is it only a minor mistake?

Any help on further reading regarding the syntax of returning functions is also much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's make this somewhat readable...

```
switchFirstEgg ec
     = if ec 1 == 0
        then sc where sc pos = if pos == 1
                                then 2
                                else ec pos
        else if ec 1 == 1
              then sc where sc pos = if pos == 1
                                      then 0
                                      else ec pos
              else if ec 1 == 2
                    then sc where sc pos = if position == 1
                                            then 1
                                            else ec pos
                    else sc where sc pos = ec pos
```

Now. `where` can only be used once per *definition*, i.e. after you wrote `switchFirstEgg _ = ...` you can follow a `where` which is valid for everything after that `=`. Or, you could more locally use a where after one of those definitions of `sc`. But you can't stick it anywhere in the middle of your code, like in an `if` branch.

The very similar `let` construct does allow this, so the easiest translation of what you attempted would be

```
switchFirstEgg ec
     = if ec 1 == 0
        then let sc pos = if pos == 1 then 2
                                      else ec pos
             in sc
        else if ec 1 == 1
              then let sc pos = if pos == 1 then 0
                                            else ec pos
                   in sc
              else if ec 1 == 2
                    then let sc pos = if pos == 1 then 1
                                                  else ec pos
                         in sc
                    else let sc pos = ec pos
                         in sc
```

but that's clunky. You don't really need to define `sc` with a name if it's used only once, immediately after the definition. That's a clear application for lambdas:

```
switchFirstEgg ec
     = if ec 1 == 0
        then \pos -> if pos == 1 then 2
                                 else ec pos
        else if ec 1 == 1
              then \pos -> if pos == 1 then 0
                                       else ec pos
              else if ec 1 == 2
                    then \pos -> if pos == 1 then 1
                                             else ec pos
                    else \pos -> ec pos
```

Better, but this chain of `if` is obviously better expressed as a single collection of `case` clauses.

```
switchFirstEgg ec = case ec 1 of
     0 -> \pos -> if pos == 1 then 2
                              else ec pos
     1 -> \pos -> if pos == 1 then 0
                              else ec pos
     2 -> \pos -> if pos == 1 then 1
                              else ec pos
     _ -> \pos -> ec pos
```

At this point it becomes clear that the `pos` bindings are pretty uniform, so we can just move them all one level up:

```
switchFirstEgg ec pos = case ec 1 of
     0 -> if pos == 1 then 2
                      else ec pos
     1 -> if pos == 1 then 0
                      else ec pos
     2 -> if pos == 1 then 1
                      else ec pos
     _ -> ec pos
```

There we have `if`s immediately following pattern matches. This is now a perfect fit for *guards*:

```
switchFirstEgg ec pos = case ec 1 of
     0 | pos == 1  -> 2
     1 | pos == 1  -> 0
     2 | pos == 1  -> 1
     _ -> ec pos
```

Alternatively, you can just match immediately on `pos`, before even considering `ec 1`:

```
switchFirstEgg ec 1 = case ec 1 of
     0   -> 2
     1   -> 0
     2   -> 1
     n   -> n
switchFirstEgg ec pos = ec pos
```

Comment: I disagree that replacing `eggCarton` with `ec` and `switchedCarton` with `sc` contributes to readability. Otherwise, this is a good answer.

Comment: @WolfeFan: well, in this case the original version was very hard to read simply due to its enourmous width. It's certainly not always a good idea to shorten down variables to two letters, but any name that's written out as often as eight times _should_ be kept short (or at least locally aliased to something short).

Comment: Nice answer. Note that the very last answer will crash if `pos` is `1` and `ec 1` is `3`, unlike the previous alternatives, since the case is non exhaustive. Of course, one can add `_ -> ec pos` to the case to prevent that.

Comment: @chi: right. Or `n -> n`, which I'd prefer (since it only evaluates `ec pos ≡ ec 1` once). Added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation, that helped a lot! :)
But I really had a harder time understanding it with these variable names ;) You can change it back to the longer ones if you like or I can do it as I think it would be easier for others, too!
Reducing the indentation was indeed helping readability.

Comment: Well, in the final version I _could_ make the variable names longer again, but I would still prefer the abbreviated names. For a small scope like this, there's no need for the names themselves to be very descriptive, just unambiguous. It's not the purpose of a parameter variable name to _explain what the parameter is there for_, that should be clarified int the type signature (which is, after all, the only thing that appears in interface docs).

Answer (score 3):

See if this does what you want:

```
switchFirstEgg eggCarton = 
  switchedCarton
  where switchedCarton = case (eggCarton 1) of
                         0 -> \position -> if position == 1
                                           then 2
                                           else eggCarton position
                         1 -> \position -> if position == 1
                                           then 0
                                           else eggCarton position
                         2 -> \position -> if position == 1
                                           then 1
                                           else eggCarton position
                         _ -> \position -> eggCarton position
```

You can only have one `where` clause in a function definition (although function definitions within `where` clauses can have their own where clauses).